# Button with image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this code:

```
.subbmitCommentBtn {
  background: url("../images/ikon2.png") no-repeat center top;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 56px;
  width: 253px;
  background-color: #AF191F;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}

<input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz" class=" subbmitCommentBtn">
```

I need to add more space on the left. I would like the picture to move away from the left edge of the button (ex. padding left:10px).

How to fix it?

Comment: Can please add button screen-short with image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background-position rather than the padding. By default, the background also covers the padding, so changing the padding doesn't influence that.

```css
.subbmitCommentBtn {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOZcL.png") no-repeat center top;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 56px;
  width: 253px;
  background-color: #AF191F;
  background-position: 10px top;     /* changed from "left" */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz" class="subbmitCommentBtn">
```

Please note that I also had to change the background image URL for the purpose of this snippet, so don't copy the whole bunch over.

Comment: Strange; it works for me in various browsers. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I use MacOS and Safari, but I have this problem too with Chrome and FireFox

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-position` to get padding effect. An example below:

```css
.subbmitCommentBtn {
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/04/01/54/paper-planes-3128885_1280.png") no-repeat; /* added an image for snippet */
  background-size: 40px 40px; /* set background-size: 40px width and 40px height  */
  background-position: 15px center; /* left:15px and vertical-align:middle */
  color: #f4f6f9;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 56px;
  width: 253px;
  background-color: #d94452;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz" class="subbmitCommentBtn">
```